# Why does SerializationInfo not have TryGetValue methods?

Tags: c#, serialization, exception

When implementing the `ISerializable` interface in C#, we provide a constructor which takes a `SerializationInfo` object, and then queries it with various `GetInt32`, `GetObject` etc. methods in order to fill the fields of the object which we are trying to deserialize.

One major reason to implement this interface, rather than just using the `[Serializable]` attribute, is for backwards compatibility: if we have added new fields to the class at some point, we can catch the `SerializationException` thrown by a serialized, older version of the class, and handle them in an appropriate manner.

My question is the following: why do we have to use these exceptions for what is, essentially, control flow? If I am deserializing a large number of classes which were saved some time ago, potentially each missing field in each class will throw an exception, causing really bad performance.

Why does the `SerializationInfo` class not provide `TryGetValue` methods which would simply return `false` if the name string were not present?

Comment: Ask whoever implemented that class

Comment: well maybe they're here :P

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can iterate over the available fields and use `switch`, though...

```
foreach(SerializationEntry entry in info) {
    switch(entry.Name) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or you could use protobuf-net ;-p

Comment: cool; this doesn't seem to be documented in the VS2008 documentation.

Comment: Agreed. This doesn't appear to be documented anywhere. Nothing seems to say that SerializationInfo is enumerable. But, it worked for me.

Comment: @Michael except [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.getenumerator.aspx) of course, or (@Joel) going back to 1.1, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.getenumerator(v=VS.71).aspx)

Comment: And this, friends, is one of the very few valid uses of the for/switch antipattern.

Comment: @BenBurns the "for/switch" antipattern concerns a particular poor coding standard as described in its Wiki. Other than that bad example, there are a **ton** of, not a few, valid use cases of a switch inside a for.

Answer (score 3):

Well no one answered 'why', but I'm guessing that's addressed to MS..

My implementation for anyone in need:

```
public static class SerializationInfoExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetValue<T>(this SerializationInfo serializationInfo, string name, out T value)
    {
        try
        {
            value = (T) serializationInfo.GetValue(name, typeof(T));
            return true;
        }
        catch (SerializationException)
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this SerializationInfo serializationInfo, string name, Lazy<T> defaultValue)
    {
        try
        {
            return (T) serializationInfo.GetValue(name, typeof(T));
        }
        catch (SerializationException)
        {
            return defaultValue.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may be useful syntactic sugar in many cases, it doesn't address the underlying problem of avoiding an exception being thrown and caught for every missing field. Indeed, in some cases (where a group of fields that would always be serialized together had a single try/catch block around them), it may make performance worse, as an exception would be generated for every missing field, rather than once for the entire group.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the enumerating solution, there is an internal method `SerializationInfo.GetValueNoThrow()` according to the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/serializationinfo.cs,832aeca1bb224271,references).

You can e.g. make an extension method like this and avoid the exception overhead:

```
static class SerializationInfoExtensions
{
    private static MethodInfo _GetValueNoThrow =
        typeof(SerializationInfo).GetMethod("GetValueNoThrow",
                                            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    public static Object GetValueNoThrow(this SerializationInfo info, String name, Type type)
    {
        return _GetValueNoThrow.Invoke(info, new object[] { name, type });
    }
}
```

This solution still results in some reflection overhead compared to a plain method call, but it is an order of magnitude smaller – [a crude benchmark at .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1nmct9):

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ExceptionOverhead | 72.840 ms | 2.0690 ms | 2.2997 ms |
| ReflectionOverhead | 2.657 ms | 0.0192 ms | 0.0205 ms |

---

However, it should be noted that the whole `SerializationInfo` type is going to be deprecated in a future version of .NET, as discussed in [Add SerializationInfo.TryGetValue API #42460](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42460).

Comment: ...of course now you have to deal with the _reflection overhead_ instead of the exception overhead.

Comment: That's a fair point, thank you. I have added some benchmark to the answer to give readers an idea whether the extra hassle is worth it.

Comment: To be fair, you can convert a `MethodInfo` to a `Func<>` call with some `System.Reflection.Emit` and the runtime cost overhead essentially disappears.