# Returning ViewBag as JSONResult result in null data?? wtf?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

What am i missing? i am trying to do the following:

```
public JsonResult LoggedOn()
    {


        ViewBag.FirstName = "todd";
        ViewBag.LastName = "billings"
        ViewBag.Email = "me@rad.com";

        return Json(ViewBag, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

The result in the js making this call is NULL/empty? There is no built in conversion of viewbag to JSON result? What am i missing? If do this with any other object it converts it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag` is a [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) as such there's nothing for the json converter to reflect against. Your best bet here would probably be to make an anonymous object rather than rely on the `ViewBag`

Here's an example found on stackoverflow: [Can I serialize an ExpandoObject in .NET 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853574/can-i-serialize-an-expandoobject-in-net-4)

Comment: BuildStarted is correct, you need to do something like this : return Json(new {FirstName = "todd", LastName = "billings", Email = "me@rad.com"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);